# Set javascript Fullcalendar plugin base on timezone (GMT + 8)

Tags: javascript, php, html, date, datetime

I am using Fullcalendar plugin:

http://fullcalendar.io/

The problem is ,I found the calendar is quite confusing, as when I click on 00:00 am , it is 8:00 a.m if I logging the date

How to restrict the display date is same as the timezone, so that if I click on 00:00 , it is actually 00:00 GMT+8 , instead of 08:00 GMT + 8 ?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Have you tried to change the Timezone? http://fullcalendar.io/docs/timezone/timezone/

Comment: share your current code snippet

Comment: setting parameter "timezone: false" in the calender script should do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use like:

```
<?php
    $datetime = new DateTime('now', 'America/Chicago');
    $datetime_string = $datetime->format('c');
?>

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    now: <?php echo json_encode($datetime_string) ?>
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 4):

You have to set timezone property of this plugin. Like this -

```
var currentTimezone = "Asia/Bangkok";
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                timezone: currentTimezone, << SET TIMEZONE HERE
                editable: true,
                selectable: true,
                eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            });
```

After setting timezone property your calendar will work base on that timezone.

Check official demo here - [DEMO](http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.5.0/demos/timezones.html)